# Changing the order of words

Tags: word-order

The original sentence is

> *Er geht um sieben Uhr zur Arbeit.*

It is okay to say

> *Um sieben Uhr geht er zur Arbeit.*

However, how about

> *Zur Arbeit geht er um sieben Uhr?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, word order in German is flexible: You can move around nearly every part of a sentence except the verbs.

However, deviating from the natural order will emphasize parts of the sentence. The more you deviate, the stronger the emphasis.

> Er geht um sieben Uhr zur Arbeit.

is neutral.

> Um sieben Uhr geht er zur Arbeit.

emphasizes the time, but not extraordinarily so.

> Zur Arbeit geht er um sieben Uhr.

emphasizes "zur Arbeit" very strongly: It is (really) work he goes to at seven o'clock.

And as you can see, English has a similar construction using "it is X that/who/...". For the same reason, the literal translation of this construction "Es ist X der/die/das ..." is rarely used, that's a common mistake by English native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Your last one is also correct. This question is put by someone who is unsure whether the time is seven.

> Zur Arbeit geht er um sieben Uhr? Und nicht um acht?

Comment: The last sentence also works without a question mark.